# Как убрать hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[ссылка на  codepen](https://codepen.io/andrey-orlov-the-sasster/pen/pooBXVQ)
Как убрать hover эффекты с помощью скрипта на экранах меньше 992px?

```
$('.hover').hover( function() {
  if ($('window').width() >=992) {
    $('.hover').addClass('hover-id');
  } else {
    $('.hover').removeClass('hover-id')
  }
  $('.hover').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.hover').removeClass('hover-id')
  });
});
$('.cover').hover( function() {
  $('.cover').addClass('hover-id');
  $('.cover').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.cover').removeClass('hover-id')
  });
});
$('.nover').hover( function() {
  $('.nover').addClass('hover-id');
  $('.nover').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.nover').removeClass('hover-id')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($(document).width() >= 992) {
      $('.news-cards').on('mouseenter', '.hover, .cover, .nover', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover-id');
      });

      $('.news-cards').on('mouseleave', '.hover, .cover, .nover', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover-id');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ответ найден](https://codepen.io/andrey-orlov-the-sasster/pen/pooBXVQ)

```
$('.hover').hover( function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)").matches) {
    $('.hover').addClass('hover-id');
  } else {
    $('.hover').removeClass('hover-id')
  }
  $('.hover').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.hover').removeClass('hover-id')
  });
});
```